# Casting custom ScrollView to ScrollView

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have got a custom scrollview that looks like this:

```
public class PagerScrollView extends ScrollView {

    float touchX = 0;
    float touchY = 0;

    ViewPager parentPager;

    public void setParentPager(ViewPager parentPager) {
        this.parentPager = parentPager;
    }

    public PagerScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PagerScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchX = ev.getX();
                touchY = ev.getY();
                return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (Math.abs(touchX-ev.getX()) < 40) {
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                } else {
                    if (parentPager == null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return parentPager.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    }
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchX = 0;
                touchY = 0;
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

In the xml, I wrap it around a ViewPager and a TabLayout (maybe this is the error?). When I try to assign it using

```
PagerScrollView pagerScrollView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager_scroll_view);
```

I get:

```
android.widget.ScrollView cannot be cast to exampleapplication.PagerScrollView
```

How can I cast it correctly?

Comment: Can you please share your xml where you use PagerScrollView as well.

Comment: Can you post your XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used a normal ScrollView in the xml instead of my <exampleapplication.CustomScrollView>. Replacing that fixed my problem.